# What is the vim way to mark in insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode, visual-mode

I've been using vim for not that long and got stuck with marking when I'm in the insert mode. I do it as follows:

1. `<ESC>v`
2. Mark the text I need
3. Do something with it
4. Enter to the insert mode again

Now I think that the approach taken by classical editors (hold CTRL+SHIFT and then press `LEFT` or `RIGHT`) is a little bit convenient. Especially if we need to select just one word we just typed (I'm not talking here about compilicated visual blocks). I think so because we don't press `<ESC>v`.

Maybe there is a simpler way to mark while we are in insert mode?

Comment: It allows us to use text objects which are much more flexible and quick then just using `<left><left><left><left>`. Try `<Esc>viw` for highlighting the current word and check out `:h  text-objects` for more and better ways to select text.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy the function "use ctrl-[left/right] to select direction-wise until word bound you can bind

```
:inoremap <c-left> <esc>vb
:inoremap <c-right> <esc>ve
```

or `<esc>viw` to instead visual around the entire word you're currently inside (or right at the end of.)

I use a similar technique in my `.vimrc` to be able to quickly uppercase my entire last word (e.g. if i wrote `max_timeout` but wanted `MAX_TIMEOUT`).
My binding for this is `:inoremap <c-u> <esc>vawUea`. The idea is the same - you bind something(`<c-u>`) to exit insert mode(`<esc>`), go into visual(`v`), do what you need to do(`U`), and then jump back into insert mode again(`ea`).

If you're worried about overwriting a predefined binding when you map on something like `<c-u>` or `<c-left>`, you can look it up with `:help <c-left>`.